# Stuck synchronizing small blockchain on test network

Tags: synchronization

I am running a test network and I am stuck with the following logs.

```
2022-03-31 16:06:33.886 I **********************************************************************
2022-03-31 16:06:33.886 I The daemon will start synchronizing with the network. This may take a long time to complete.
2022-03-31 16:06:33.886 I 
2022-03-31 16:06:33.886 I You can set the level of process detailization through "set_log <level|categories>" command,
2022-03-31 16:06:33.886 I where <level> is between 0 (no details) and 4 (very verbose), or custom category based levels (eg, *:WARNING).
2022-03-31 16:06:33.886 I 
2022-03-31 16:06:33.886 I Use the "help" command to see the list of available commands.
2022-03-31 16:06:33.886 I Use "help <command>" to see a command's documentation.
2022-03-31 16:06:33.886 I **********************************************************************
2022-03-31 16:06:33.923 I [107.20.71.167:15668 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1 -> 9 [Your node is 8 blocks (8.0 minutes) behind] 
2022-03-31 16:06:33.923 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
```

As you can see there are very few blocks on my network and I had it where it would sync almost instantly. Then suddenly it stopped syncing altogether and gives me this error. Any ideas?

Also the designated seed nodes sync instantly but the other nodes do not.

Comment: Nevermind. I needed to open a port I think.

Comment: https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet